# onReceive() android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

In my application need to check the internet connection changes. So we register the receiver "android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" and in the onReceive() handle the connectivity change like as below code.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    { 
        if (action.equals(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            // handle netwrk changes code
        }
    }
 };
```

The above code is working fine and it handles the internet connectivity changes. But the problem is when I goes to some other activity and come back to this activity the onReceive() method will executed because receive the broadcast for "***android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION***" which I don't want it. Can anybody know why this is happening?

When I come back to the activity I don't want to receive the broadcast for *`"android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION"`*.

Comment: then try to declare broadcast reciever in seprate class in place of your activity class

Answer (score 1):

try creating broadcast reciever in seprate BroadcastReceiver  class when not get called with your activity

```
public class Netreciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 if (action.equals(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        // handle netwrk changes code
    }
 }
```

manifest.xml

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".Netreciever"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: still "android.net.conn.Connectivity_change is getting called.

Comment: Why it's getting called when comes back to the activity